# Programmatically delete all text between 2 characters in osx terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I have a thousand of txt files

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

in each files, several times I have tags among my text:

```
{somethinghere...blablabla} than the text I want to keep than again {somethinghere...blablabla}
```

I'm not very pratical in mac osx command line, can someone help me to write a command opening each file, parsing it, and deleting all text included by two "{"?

To be clear:

First of all I need to open each file, than parse the text. When the loop finds a "{" it starts deleting till it founds a "}". When done parsing it saves and close the file. That's what I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $ sed -i.bak -e 's@{[^}]*}@@g' *.txt
```

- `-i.bak` make a backup copy of each modified files. If you don't want backups, on OsX use `-i''` (the quotes are not necessary on Linux)
- in substitutions, the delimiter can be another character than `/`, here I choose `@`, so : `s@<REGEX>@<REMPLACEMENT>@` (the basic form for substitutions are `s///`)
- In the regex, we search a litteral `{` and all but not a `}` with `[^}]`. `*` means 0 or more occurences. Last, we search the closing `}` and we replace the matching part by nothing, so it delete what was matching
- the `g` modifier @the end means not only one match but all

Comment: Oh yeah indeed, you already gave me the final code, I didn't realize it was so "easy" Thanks a lot

Comment: Yeah, right :) Just can you explain me the rule of the regular expression? I'd like to understand even if you already gave me the right answer :)

Comment: Nice, I see. And g should stand for replace and s = regular expression? I saw the command sed page meanwhile :P

Comment: POST re-edited accordingly. the basic form for substitutions are `s///`, so the s comes from that